# Extend developer sign up on Azure Api Management

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

Is there any way to extend the form of the sign up for the developers in the Azure Api Management Developer Portal so i can ask for an extre field?

I currently need to ask for the ID of the developer (A number) on the sign up process, and i need to use this ID later on to perform some validations.

Is there any way to do this without having to use a custom identity provider?

Answer (score 0):

No, but there is a way to delegate signup and product subscription: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-setup-delegation